# Get the Hour from a date time field with the current time zone in a formula field

Tags: formula, datetime

I create a custom field to display the hour and the minute of a date time field.

The format I need is HH:MM

For now, I get the hour in GMT but it is wrong because I am in France and the time zone mooves.

During a half of the year, we are in GMT+1 and for the rest, we are in GMT+2.

Do you knom how I can get the hour in current timezone?

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar myself recently. The solution I went with involved two fields, one for checking whether the date within another field was within Daylight Savings Time, and another to translate a date field into a verbose text output e.g. `6:00 PM Friday, December 10, 2016`.

It sounds like you could use a similar solution, use a field to determine which side of the +1/+2 the field should be in, then use a formula like `IF(Field_is_gmt1__c, date_field__c + 1/24, date_field__c + 2/24)`

Checking if a field's date is within DST (these are the US DST dates, not sure if they vary in France):

```
AND( 
Event__r.EventDate__c >= 
DATE(YEAR(Event__r.EventDate__c),3,8) + MOD(7 - MOD(DATE(YEAR(Event__r.EventDate__c),3,8) - DATE(1900,1,7),7) , 7) 
, 
Event__r.EventDate__c < 
DATE(YEAR(Event__r.EventDate__c),11,1) + MOD(7 - MOD(DATE(YEAR(Event__r.EventDate__c),11,1) - DATE(1900,1,7),7) , 7) 
)
```

Comment: the DST is fragile as the 'day of month' changes from year-to-year and not all US jurisdictions use DST